# Optimizing grid based inventory

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine, inventory

I am trying to create a grid based inventory and so far everything is going well except for one thing.

The inventory consists of `Grids` that are built of `Cells`, `Grids` can have custom size (like 5x3, 3x3). Every `Cell` is always 1x1 and can hold `Items` which can be of different sizes (like `Grids`).

I am handling the interactions in inventory using `HandleCursor` function which I run every frame to check if user is highlighting items/cells or moving stuff around.

As you can see in the code below I'm using a lot of fors to do that and I'am wondering if I could optimize it somehow so it isn't this hard on the CPU (right now highlighting a grid/item makes my inventory script create an overhead of 0.27-0.31ms.

Is there any better alternative than checking if `Rect` of each `Cell` contains my cursor?

Sorry if this is a wrong place to ask this kind of questions.

My code:

```
        void HandleHighlighting()
        {
            HandleHighlightingCells();

            HandleHighlightingItems();

            HandleHighlightingPickedItem();
        }
```

Highlighting **all** cells in all grids:

```
        void HandleHighlightingCells()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Grids.Count; i++)
            {
                InventoryGrid grid = Grids[i];

                if (grid.GetRect().Contains(Input.mousePosition))
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < grid.width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < grid.height; y++)
                        {
                            InventoryCell cell = grid.cells[x, y];
                            if (cell.GetRect().Contains(Input.mousePosition))
                            {
                                if (highlightedCell && highlightedCell != cell)
                                {
                                    highlightedCell.Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.NONE);
                                }

                                highlightedCell = cell;
                                highlightedCell.Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.BASE);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (cell == highlightedCell)
                                {
                                    highlightedCell = null;
                                }

                                cell.Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.NONE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < grid.width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < grid.height; y++)
                        {
                            InventoryCell cell = grid.cells[x, y];

                            if (highlightedCell && highlightedCell != cell)
                            {
                                if (highlightedCell.grid == grid)
                                {
                                    highlightedCell = null;
                                }


                            }

                            cell.Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.NONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Highlighting items in inventory:

```
        void HandleHighlightingItems()
        {
            if (highlightedCell && highlightedCell.heldItem)
            {
                InventoryItem item = highlightedCell.heldItem;

                if (highlightedItem && highlightedItem != item)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < highlightedItem.occupiedCells.Length; i++)
                    {
                        highlightedItem.occupiedCells[i].Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.NONE);
                    }
                }

                highlightedItem = item;

                for (int i = 0; i < item.occupiedCells.Length; i++)
                {
                    item.occupiedCells[i].Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.BASE);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (highlightedItem)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < highlightedItem.occupiedCells.Length; i++)
                    {
                        highlightedItem.occupiedCells[i].Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.NONE);
                    }

                    highlightedItem = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Highlighting picked items:

```
        void HandleHighlightingPickedItem()
        {
            if (pickedItem)
            {
                if (highlightedCell)
                {
                    InventoryGrid grid = highlightedCell.grid;
                    InventoryCell[] cellsToHighlight = new InventoryCell[pickedItem.width * pickedItem.height];
                    InventoryItem firstItem = null;

                    bool valid = true;

                    int index = 0;
                    for (int x = 0; x < pickedItem.width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < pickedItem.height; y++)
                        {
                            if (highlightedCell.x + x < grid.width && highlightedCell.y + y < grid.height)
                            {
                                InventoryCell cell = grid.cells[highlightedCell.x + x, highlightedCell.y + y];
                                cellsToHighlight[index] = cell;

                                if (highlightedItem)
                                {
                                    if (cell.heldItem != highlightedItem)
                                    {
                                        if (cell.heldItem)
                                        {
                                            valid = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (cell.heldItem)
                                    {
                                        if (!firstItem)
                                        {
                                            firstItem = cell.heldItem;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (cell.heldItem != firstItem)
                                            {
                                                valid = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                valid = false;
                            }

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < cellsToHighlight.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (cellsToHighlight[i])
                        {
                            if (valid)
                            {
                                cellsToHighlight[i].Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.VALID);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cellsToHighlight[i].Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.INVALID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Theres' a code review site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Adelin Thank you, I'll post there

Comment: Although I'm not sure if it's the right place. Check that help center as well. I might have seen something in the lines of *[...]examples of titles that are unacceptable[...]: [Simplify this chain of if statements (Applies to too many questions.)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)*

Comment: @Adelin It got edited but I suppose the rest fits just right

Answer (score 0):

With help of t3chb0t and juvian from codereview.stackexchange.com I managed to reduce the overhead from ~0.31ms to <0.08ms.

I actually ended up only changing the function that highlights all cells.

I'm posting this as an answer so it's visible in case someone else has similar problem.

```
void HandleHighlightingCells()
{
    Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    bool anyHighlighted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < Grids.Count; i++)
    {
        InventoryGrid grid = Grids[i];

        if (grid.GetRect().Contains(mousePos))
        {
            Vector2 uiPos = Vector2.zero;
            RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(grid.cellsRoot.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), Input.mousePosition, GameManager.singleton.inventoryCanvas.worldCamera, out uiPos);

            //64 is the constant size of a cell
            int cellX = Mathf.FloorToInt(uiPos.x / 64);
            int cellY = Mathf.FloorToInt(-uiPos.y / 64);

            if(cellX < grid.width && cellY < grid.height)
            {
                cellX = Mathf.Clamp(cellX, 0, grid.width - 1);
                cellY = Mathf.Clamp(cellY, 0, grid.height - 1);

                InventoryCell cell = grid.cells[cellX, cellY];

                if (highlightedCell && highlightedCell != cell)
                {
                    highlightedCell.Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.NONE);
                }

                highlightedCell = cell;
                highlightedCell.Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.BASE);

                anyHighlighted = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!anyHighlighted)
    {
        if(highlightedCell)
        {
            highlightedCell.Highlight(EItemHighlightMode.NONE);
            highlightedCell = null;
        }
    }
}
```